# IF statements in SQL Server triggers

Tags: if-statement, triggers, sql-server-2014

I need to create a SQL Server trigger to block updates and deletes to a table `Service`.

This action should be done only to `Service` in which the column `State`s sample data is "completed".

It should allow updates and deletes to  `Service` in which the column `State`s sample data is "active".

This is what I tried, I am having problems with doing the else operation (that is allowing updates to `Service` in which the column `State` sample data is "active").

```
CREATE TRIGGER [Triggername]
ON dbo.Service
FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
    DECLARE @para varchar(10),
            @results varchar(50)

    SELECT @para = Status
    FROM Service

    IF (@para = 'completed') 
    BEGIN
        SET @results = 'An invoiced service cannot be updated or deleted!';
        SELECT @results;
    END

BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('An invoiced service cannot be updated or deleted', 16, 1)
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

    RETURN 
END
```

Comment: If you want to block updates and deletes - then why is the trigger on `INSERT` as well?? Also: you're never looking at the `Deleted` and `Inserted` pseudo tables which tell you *what* rows have been updated (or deleted) - so this isn't going to work......

Comment: it returns the value, 'An invoiced service cannot be updated or deleted!'. but i'm not sure whether it checks the if condition

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand you correctly, any `UPDATE` or `DELETE` should be allowed if the `State` column has a value of `Active`, but stopped in any other case??

Then I'd do this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [Triggername]
ON dbo.Service
FOR UPDATE, DELETE
AS
BEGIN
   -- if any row exists in the "Deleted" pseudo table of rows that WERE 
   -- in fact updated or deleted, that has a state that is *not* "Active"
   -- then abort the operation
   IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Deleted WHERE State <> 'Active')
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

   -- otherwise let the operation finish 
END
```

As a note: you *cannot* easily return messages from a trigger (with `SELECT @Results`) - the trigger just silently fails by rolling back the currently active transaction

Comment: What do i do if i have to return an output saying "An invoiced service cannot be updated or deleted!" for completed services .

Comment: When i execute this code , it returns error, "Incorrect syntax near 'END'."

Comment: @Ayyub: as I tried to say: you *cannot* return anything from a trigger - no message, no number - the trigger just works silently in the background. If you need a message like this, you need to check *before* deleting / updating if that operation would be allowed (or not).

Comment: Works perfectly  to support the basic requirement. My project also requires to return the message as mentioned. I there any other way to do that?

Comment: @Ayyub: as I said in my previous comment : in that case, you need to check *before* the operation if something could go wrong and show a message ....